# What field in Active Directory should be populated to allow e-mail alerts?

Tags: email, active-directory, alert

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but none of the questions I've found so far seem to answer this specific question.

I have a SharePoint site where no users (or almost no users) can create alerts because they get the message:

> The following users do not have e-mail addresses specified: DOMAIN.COM\username. Alerts have been created successfully but these users will not receive e-mail notifications until valid e-mail addresses have been provided

All of these users are domain users, and all have Exchange mailboxes in the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Active Directory Field is "Mail". Have a look at one of the affected users by opening that user's profile in SharePoint. You'll see that the Email address field is probably empty? Check that your Time Service account (Farm account) has access to read Active directory properties.

Comment: This was what I suspected, but I had other people telling me different things. It turns out that 24 hours after updating the mail field on all these users it has started to work :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually update each user's email address though. SharePoint has a timer job which does that for you. All you need to do is make sure that the timer job service account has access to read Active Directory Properties.

Comment: Also make sure that in your User Profile Service, the email field has an in coming property from AD, which should be "mail"